# Python. Merge dict rows with SUM

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a lot of dict rows, more than 10 million, like this:

```py
{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '25'}
{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '35'}
{'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '901', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '55'}
{'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '15'}
```

Is it possible to merge rows where all others key and values are the same into one make SUM of `'bytes':` 
I would like to minimize the number of rows and have like this. It should  speed up the next steps of processing.

```py
{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '60'}
{'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '901', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '55'}
{'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '15'}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: That said, most applications will use PANDAS (data frame) for this.  If you want to do that, work through a PANDAS tutorial.  Watch for the `groupby` and `sum` methods.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an intermediate dictionary indexed on all "other" keys, you can accumulate the 'byte' values in a common dictionary for each combination of other fields.  then convert the indexed values back into a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '25'},
       {'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '35'},
       {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '901', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '55'},
       {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '15'}]

merged = dict()
for d in lst:
    k = map(d.get,sorted({*d}-{"bytes"}))  # index on all other fields
    m = merged.setdefault(tuple(k),d)      # add/get first instance
    if m is not d:                         # accumulate bytes (as strings) 
        m['bytes'] = str(int(m['bytes']) + int(d['bytes']))
mergedList = list(merged.values())

print(mergedList)
[{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '60'},
 {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '901', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '55'},
 {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '15'}]
```

This will work without sorting (i.e in O(n) time) even if your data is not grouped by the combination of other fields.  It will also work if the order of keys are different.  Missing keys would be problematic but can be taken into account using a comprehension instead of `map(d.get,`.

*Note that you really should store the byte counts as integers instead of strings*

Answer (score 0):

the code below should work

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '25'},
       {'value_01': '123', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '1', 'bytes': '35'},
       {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '901', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '55'},
       {'value_01': '678', 'value_02': '456', 'datacenter': '2', 'bytes': '15'}]
keys = ['value_01', 'value_02', 'datacenter']
data = defaultdict(int)
for entry in lst:
    key = tuple([entry[key] for key in keys])
    data[key] += int(entry['bytes'])
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('123', '456', '1'): 60, ('678', '901', '2'): 55, ('678', '456', '2'): 15})
```